# Only first <hr> is not showing

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, tags

I had the issue that a simple `<hr>` wasn't showing on a page I'm working on and while fiddling around with this problem I noticed the following: If I have multipe`<hr>` tags on the page only the first one won't show up, the others however will. I tried this already in multiple combinations. In the developer tools of my browser I can't find any difference between an invisible and a non-invisible `<hr>`.

Here a little piece of example code:

```
        <div>
            <p>A</p>
            <hr>
            <p>B</p>
            <hr>
            <p>C</p>
        </div>
```

Only the line between B and C is visible.

Does someone have any idea what is causing this?

Btw: I am using Bootstrap 4 and haven't altered the `<hr>` tag with CSS in any way.

**Edit:**

I added some CSS to change the border and this is what I get:

[image: screenshot]

The upper line is clearly thinner.
Here the CSS:

```
hr {
    border-top: 5px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Not really enough info there to help... do you have a URL we can have a look at? I've just created a JSFiddle with Bootstrap 4 CSS and your HTML and both the `hr` tags are displayed (https://jsfiddle.net/ojtramp/g37mhc1s/)

Comment: Sorry I'm still working on this page and don't have an URL. However I just had another discovery which I describe in the edited part of my post.

Comment: Can you copy your page HTML, etc into a JSFiddle? The fact that the first `hr` is visible when you change the `border-top` means that it is being outputed. As a guess... it looks like there might be some CSS selector that somehow only effects the first `hr`.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot your closing slash on the tag(s). Do it like this:

```
<div>
    <p>A</p>
    <hr/>
    <p>B</p>
    <hr/>
    <p>C</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can play with height of the horizontal line to set a precise value, but it also should works with borders.

```css
hr{
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #000;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<div>   
   <p>A</p>
   <hr>
   <p>B</p>
   <hr>
   <p>C</p>
</div>
```